# Matplotlib: Change size of subplot in figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

i am struggling to shrink my plot inside the figure.
When saving the plot as a picture, the borders of the window are really close to
the actual plot. How do I create more space between them?
[This is the saved picture, the arrows show where I want to insert more space.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boh0b.png)

I already tried

```
figsize = (...)
```

and played with the numbers, but I it only changes the size of the figure.